# Ways to run django on google app engine that uses ndb

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I'm trying to shift the existing webapp2 and jinjia2 templating to Django. But the initial Django project that I wanted to shift that was also stated on Google website [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/django-nonrel?hl=en) has been deprecated hence I'm worried that there will be no more support in the future if I continue using it. What are the other Django project that I could use. One important criteria is that I could still use the ndb datastore with the new Django framework. I found two other alternative:
[Django App Engine](http://djangoappengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html)
and
[Djangae](https://potatolondon.github.io/djangae/).
May I know what are the difference between them or are there other alternatives out there?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: You can use NDB with a regular Django instalation, but the datastore will not be used under the hood when you use the Django ORM. But I am not sure using a NoSQL under Django ORM is a good idea anyways. The query language is not designed for NoSQL. So if you want to use Django ORM, why not using Cloud SQL?

Comment: Your question is OT, but have a look at this: https://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine